# returning estimated parameters using VBA

Tags: function, vba

I have the below function that I am using to enter 2 initial parameters, rho and V, and based on minimized sum of squared errors, I want it to return the estimated parameters, rho and V.

```
Public Function RhoAndV(params, MktStrike, MktVol, Vol, Fwd, Tau, Beta)
    Dim rho, V, Alpha As Double
    Dim i As Integer, L As Integer
    Dim sqdError() As Double, ModelVol() As Double
    rho = params(1)
    V = params(2)
    Alpha = AFn(Fwd, Fwd, Tau, Vol, Beta, rho, V)
    'MsgBox ("Alpha=" & Alpha)
    L = MktVol.Cells.Count
    ReDim ModelVol(L) As Double, sqdError(L) As Double
    For i = 1 To L
        ModelVol(i) = Vfn(Alpha, Beta, rho, V, Fwd, MktStrike(i), Tau)
        'MsgBox ("ModelVol(i)=" & ModelVol(i))
        sqdError(i) = (ModelVol(i) - MktVol(i)) ^ 2
    Next i
    RhoAndV = Application.SUM(sqdError)
    End Function
```

I have rho and V in cells A1:A2 with values 0.1 and 0.1, so I select A1:A2 as `params`.
In cells C3:C6, I have MktStrike with values

```
30
31
32
33
```

In cells D3:D6, I have MktVol with values

```
0.23
0.24
0.25
0.26
```

This function now returns the sumof squared errors (I run it in Excel as `=RhoAndV(A1:A3,C3:C6,D3:D6,0.25,10,1,0.5)` and it returns `.003`. However, I want it to return the estimated parameters, `rho` and `V`. Can anyone please tell me how to fix this function to do so?

Comment: A VBA function can only return a single value. If you were working within VBA, I would suggest adding `rho` and `V` as ByRef parameters to the function definition; then when the function changes the values of those parameters, you would be able to see the changes outside of the function. However, I don't think the formula in an Excel cell can make use of ByRef parameters.

Comment: Return an array from your function, and enter the formula as a formula array on the worksheet (using Ctrl+Shift+Enter)  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ReturningArraysFromVBA.aspx

Comment: @TimWilliams, agreed regd. returning an array, but how do I capture the estimated parameter, rho and V as they change in the loop, where the error is being computed. should I be recomputing these parameters within the loop and update their values there?

Comment: How do rho and V change in the loop?  Are you passing them ByRef to the function Vfn?  Do you want to return all of the values or just the final ones?

Comment: I just want to return the final values. Right now, the first loop takes the initial values of rho and V. I am not sure how to pass it ByRef and do it right.

Answer (score 1):

You'd modify your original function to something like the example below.  How you return the values depends on whether you want to return them to a row (eg D3:E3) or column (eg. D3:D4)

```
Function RhoAndV(params, MktStrike, MktVol, Vol, Fwd, Tau, Beta)

    'rest of your code

    'RhoAndV = Array(rho, V) 'returning to a row
    RhoAndV = Application.Transpose(Array(rho, V)) 'returning to a column
End Function
```

Comment: but all that does is returns the original rho and V parameters that I passed, i.e. 0.1 and 0.1. I want it to return the rho and V that it estimates in the process.

Comment: Where are those "estimated" values being generated?  Unless your original inputs are being modified in the function I don't see any other variables which could be returned. You can't return values you don't have. I have no idea what happens in your other functions `Afn` and `Vfn`, so that's all I can offer.

Comment: rather than post those functions here, I think I should go back and track that down. Thanks for your help so far.